# Any web designers here made a transition from Photoshop to Gimp?

Tags: windows, linux, adobe-photoshop, gimp

I just made the full transition to Debian from Windows XP at work ( I mainly do front end but I do some slicing/design as well ), I'm wondering if anyone else has made the Photoshop to Gimp switch, and how compatible is Gimp with Photoshop saved psd's, are the web slicing features up to par with Photoshop's? Should just rely on Photoshop in a VirtualBox XP Partition.

Comment: Would be good to rephrase the question (re: post title).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I switched to Linux a couple of years ago.  Since then, I've been using GIMP.

I work with designers doing stuff on Photoshop.  When they give me a copy of their PSDs for further editing, I end up returning to the work to them to let them do the changes because GIMP handles PSDs quite differently. **Layers are not in order** and **not all effects are rendered properly**.

GIMP has a long way to go to match Photoshop.

Comment: This is probably why: http://code.google.com/p/xee/source/browse/trunk/XeePhotoshopLoader.m?r=11#107

Comment: @LiraNuna - liked the comment "Trying to get data out of a PSD file is like trying to find something in the attic of your eccentric old uncle who died in a freak freshwater shark attack on his 58th birthday."

Comment: I wonder how much time that guy spent reverse-engineering the format that he could have saved by just reading the spec.

Comment: For posterity, the link above has now changed to http://code.google.com/p/xee/source/browse/XeePhotoshopLoader.m#108 - it's a good read.  And intuited, the author stated he tried to get the specs, but ran into too many walls doing so.

Answer (score 3):

For a while, I used Gimp and it does work (and save you a small fortune) but I have to say that I just did not like it as much. I had no problems with compatibility but I just could not get on with it.

Gimp slicing works well - my problems were mainly with actual photo effects and editing.

Also, In my experience, Photoshop runs terrible in a VM, especially the newest which uses GPU acceleration.

Comment: Which VM did you use specifically? VMWare? Virtualbox2, 3?

Comment: I used VirtualBox. I know that Vmware workstation has some nice GPU features in Windows, I have no idea for Linux and you may get some better results.